# How to show / hide html elements in Handlebars using conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I have the following in my handlebars  tag:

```
{{#editmode mode}}

    <div class="form-group login-input">
       <i class="fa fa-key overlay"></i>
       <input type="password" class="form-control text-input" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{password}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group login-input">
       <i class="fa fa-key overlay"></i>
       <input type="password" class="form-control text-input" name="password_confirmation" value="{{password}}">
     </div>

{{/editmode}}
```

and I have the following registered as my helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('editmode', function(mode){           
    return mode == 'edit' ? true : false;
});
```

The object passed to the handlebars template looks something like this:

```
{
   firstname: 'Test',
   lastname: 'Test lastname',
   mode: 'new
}
```

So basically, whenever the 'mode' variable is 'new', I want to show the password fields, otherwise hide them, but right now they are always hidden. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. This did the trick:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('editmode', function(mode, options){                      
     return mode == 'edit' ? '' : options.fn();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` statement.

```
<div class="form-group login-input">
   <i class="fa fa-key overlay"></i>
   <input type="password" class="form-control text-input" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{password}}">
</div>

{{#if mode}}
<div class="form-group login-input">
   <i class="fa fa-key overlay"></i>
   <input type="password" class="form-control text-input" name="password_confirmation" value="{{password}}">
 </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. To my mind, this should be the preferred answer as some providers like mailgun and savegrid don't give us the option to register new Handlebar helpers!